How to align text with graphs and add a bracket with Tikz?
Could anyone help align the text and the graphs as shown in the right figure?
Also, could you help with adding the brackets?
By bracket, I mean to say that the values in  YY column can form tuples of graphs from each row. For example, YY1 is the combination of the first graph from each row.
Please suggest if you know a better way than using brackets.

\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

% Define the side length, horizontal distance, and circle size as global variables
\def\sideLength{0.5}  % You can change this value
\def\hDistance{1}     % You can change this value
\def\circleSize{1.5pt}  % Circle size for the vertices

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Sample Table with Graphs Using TikZ}
    \label{tab:sample_table}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc} % 4 columns
        \toprule
        No. & XX & Graph & YY \\ % Header row
        \midrule
        1 & Value 1 & 
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill[red] (0,0) circle (\circleSize); % Draw and fill Vertex A
            \node at (0,-0.2) {A}; % Label A
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        & Value YY1 \\
        
        2 & Value 2 & 
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            % Draw the edge between A and B
            \draw[black] (0,0) -- (\sideLength,0); % Edge between A and B
            % Now fill the vertices
            \fill[red] (0,0) circle (\circleSize); % Vertex A (filled)
            \node at (0,-0.2) {A};
            \fill[red] (\sideLength,0) circle (\circleSize); % Vertex B (filled)
            \node at (\sideLength,-0.2) {B};
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        & Value YY2 \\
        
        3 & Value 3 & 
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            % Draw the edges for the first graph (equilateral triangle)
            \draw[black] (0,0) -- (\sideLength,0); % Edge A-B
            \draw[black] (\sideLength,0) -- (\sideLength/2,{\sideLength*sqrt(3)/2}); % Edge B-C
            \draw[black] (\sideLength/2,{\sideLength*sqrt(3)/2}) -- (0,0); % Edge C-A
            % Fill the vertices
            \fill[red] (0,0) circle (\circleSize); % Vertex A
            \node at (0,-0.2) {A};
            \fill[red] (\sideLength,0) circle (\circleSize); % Vertex B
            \node at (\sideLength,-0.2) {B};
            \fill[red] (\sideLength/2,{\sideLength*sqrt(3)/2}) circle (\circleSize); % Vertex C
            \node at (\sideLength/2,{\sideLength*sqrt(3)/2+0.2}) {C};
            
            % Second graph (path: edges between A-B and B-C)
            \begin{scope}[xshift=\hDistance cm]
                \draw[black] (0,0) -- (\sideLength,0); % Edge A-B
                \draw[black] (\sideLength,0) -- (\sideLength/2,{\sideLength*sqrt(3)/2}); % Edge B-C
                \fill[red] (0,0) circle (\circleSize); % Vertex A
                \node at (0,-0.2) {A};
                \fill[red] (\sideLength,0) circle (\circleSize); % Vertex B
                \node at (\sideLength,-0.2) {B};
                \fill[red] (\sideLength/2,{\sideLength*sqrt(3)/2}) circle (\circleSize); % Vertex C
                \node at (\sideLength/2,{\sideLength*sqrt(3)/2+0.2}) {C};
            \end{scope}
            
            % Third graph (star: edges from C to A and B)
            \begin{scope}[xshift=2*\hDistance cm]
                \draw[black] (\sideLength/2,{\sideLength*sqrt(3)/2}) -- (0,0); % Edge C-A
                \draw[black] (\sideLength/2,{\sideLength*sqrt(3)/2}) -- (\sideLength,0); % Edge C-B
                \fill[red] (0,0) circle (\circleSize); % Vertex A
                \node at (0,-0.2) {A};
                \fill[red] (\sideLength,0) circle (\circleSize); % Vertex B
                \node at (\sideLength,-0.2) {B};
                \fill[red] (\sideLength/2,{\sideLength*sqrt(3)/2}) circle (\circleSize); % Vertex C
                \node at (\sideLength/2,{\sideLength*sqrt(3)/2+0.2}) {C};
            \end{scope}
            
        % Fourth graph (V-shape: edges from A to C, and A to B)
        \begin{scope}[xshift=3*\hDistance cm]
            \draw[black] (0,0) -- (\sideLength/2,{\sideLength*sqrt(3)/2}); % Edge A-C
            \draw[black] (0,0) -- (\sideLength,0); % Edge A-B (corrected)
            \fill[red] (0,0) circle (\circleSize); % Vertex A
            \node at (0,-0.2) {A};
            \fill[red] (\sideLength,0) circle (\circleSize); % Vertex B
            \node at (\sideLength,-0.2) {B};
            \fill[red] (\sideLength/2,{\sideLength*sqrt(3)/2}) circle (\circleSize); % Vertex C
            \node at (\sideLength/2,{\sideLength*sqrt(3)/2+0.2}) {C};
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        & Value YY3 \\
        
        4 & Value 4 &  ...
        & Value YY4 \\
        
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}


Use option baseline={([yshift=-.5ex]current bounding box)} with all TikZ pictures to align them vertically.

I would use \def\offset{\the\dimexpr 0.5\dp\strutbox-0.5\ht\strutbox} for the yshift.  Only a slight difference: -2.4pt vs -2.25pt.
